# Integrated mic not working when headphones (no mic) are plugged in, otherwise mic recording system playback loudly alongside my voice

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 for 7 days now, and **my internal mic isn't working when my headphones (no mic on them) or external speakers are plugged into the headphone jack.** I tried looking around in pavucontrol for input on any device, but there is nothing (except monitor devices, which monitor system sound, I think). In pavucontrol, I can choose between microphone (plugged) and internal microphone (unplugged), but neither gets any input, except microphone (plugged in) getting constant noise recording that wasn't affected by my voice.

Another thing is that, only on Ubuntu, **my left headphone is making static noise**, and that's only while playing sound in the right stereo channel. If playing sound only through the left channel, the left headphone works normally. When I plug them into my phone, or earlier on Windows on the same laptop, they work normally, without any static noise. The same thing happens on my external speakers, but it's much much less noticeable and I can hear it only in a few specific songs.

The third problem, really important and probably related, is that when my headphones aren't plugged in, **my mic works well, but it also records system audio loudly and clearly**, which I haven't found a workaround for. This is really bad, as people I speak to can hear themselves on Discord, and can also hear anything I'm playing on my laptop at the time. The problem wasn't there on Windows. There is no loopback or anything similar that I could mute in alsamixer, and lowering the "Capture" bar to zero just killed all of my mic input. Lowering "Digital" didn't seem to make any change.
[Alsamixer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCYk7.png)

To summarize what I've tried:

- Using a live Linux Pop!_OS 20.10, and the same problems seem to appear.
- Installing alsamixer and trying to lower some bars in f4 (input tab) so that they don't lower my microphone but only the system sounds that keep being recorded, no help.
- Installing pavucontrol and trying to find something on input that I could mute so the system sounds would stop, and I did mute monitor for built-in mic hoping that'd make a change but nothing happened.
- Checking if there was any input on any device in pavucontrol when my headphones were plugged in, found none.
- Tried to do put my laptop to sleep, plug in the headphones, and then wake the computer, as an online thread suggested. It didn't work.
- Random terminal commands I found online.
- Rebooting a lot of times.

I've been googling a lot and asking Linux friends for advice, with absolutely no results. If I can't fix this, I'd have to go back to windows, which I'm not happy about hahah

My sound card should be Intel 100 series/C230, and this is my system probe on linux-hardware.org
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=99e25d58ad
The same site says that my sound card is supported on Linux, so I'm hoping this can be solved.

Thanks in advance!